# Django Foreign Key of Auth.User - column "user_id" does not exist

Tags: python, django

**UPDATE:**

This is probably a better representation of my question:

Using loadtestdata, how do you populate the auth.User database? I just want to populate the database with bogus users, and simulations that are linked to those bogus users.

I have looked at all relevant resources but I'm unable to make any headway.

**Situation:**

I am building a simulation model using Django and am looking to store simulation data as well as sets of parameter data. Many sets of simulation data should be linked to each user, and many sets of parameter data can be linked to each simulation. Thus, I have tried to model this under 'models.py' of my Django app.

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.


class Simulation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    # Each simulation has only one graph
    # Graphing parameters
    hill_num = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    div_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    s3_url = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sim_id)


class Parameter(models.Model):
    # Each simulation can have many sets of simulation parameters
    simulation = models.ForeignKey('Simulation', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    lsp = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    plots = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pioneer = models.BooleanField()
    neutral = models.BooleanField()

    # for pioneers
    p_max = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    p_num = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    p_start = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    # for non-pioneers
    np_max = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    np_num = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    np_start = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.param_id)
```

./manage.py makemigrations works but when I try to populate the database with `python manage.py loadtestdata auth.User:10 divexplorer.Simulation:40 divexplorer.Parameter:300`, it throws this error:

```
auth.User(pk=72): JshtkqSzw3
auth.User(pk=73): QwPfxJc_KS1k5sgH5BN98J
auth.User(pk=74): fuEhnZ
auth.User(pk=75): a
auth.User(pk=76): XjVXXLYGz3MJSfmZ54wGxXo
auth.User(pk=77): fhOWIp
auth.User(pk=78): 5tkEhKOjX2UUbFe
auth.User(pk=79): JgG4Y4PqkcapNJJOlFW1LOQ
auth.User(pk=80): fhRmfQHNim4zM8hGPzpYdkwaHI7
auth.User(pk=81): cEPQtyByKdUs8Gw58DrfNtpsCRB_
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 185, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autofixture/management/commands/loadtestdata.py", line 225, in handle
    autofixture.create(model, count, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autofixture/__init__.py", line 136, in create
    return autofixture.create(count, **create_kwargs)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autofixture/base.py", line 554, in create
    instance = self.create_one(commit=commit, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autofixture/base.py", line 519, in create_one
    instance.save()
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 807, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 837, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 923, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 962, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1076, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/evanma/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "user_id" of relation "divexplorer_simulation" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "divexplorer_simulation" ("user_id", "date", "hi...
```

I have spent hours trying to work through this error but to no avail. Any ideas?

I have tried renaming the argument db_column in the ForeignKey function, applying default values, but none of them work. Would appreciate some input thank you very much!

Comment: `makemigrations` is only one step, `migrate` the other...

Comment: when I do migrate, the console replies "No migrations to apply". So that's all fine

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify if related models should also be created with random values.

Please check the docs: http://django-autofixture.readthedocs.io/en/latest/loadtestdata.html

Where it is stated:

> There are a few command line options available. Mainly to control the behavior of related fields. If foreingkey or many to many fields should be populated with existing data or if the related models are also generated on the fly. Please have a look at the help page of the command for more information:

```
    django-admin.py help loadtestdata
```

Unfortunately I can't check a running instance of Django know in order to point you to the exact option and it's value but checking the docs I would say that you have to use this option from loadtestdata:

```
    ...
    make_option('--generate-fk', action='store', dest='generate_fk', default=None,
                    help=u'Do not use already existing instances for ForeignKey relations. ' +
                    'Create new instances instead. You can specify a comma sperated list of ' +
                    'field names or ALL to indicate that all foreignkeys should be generated ' +
                    'automatically.'),
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for replying so promptly! However, I still get the same error after applying the flags ` python manage.py loadtestdata auth.User:10 divexplorer.Simulation:40 divexplorer.Parameter:300 --generate-fk auth.User divexplorer.Simulation `